# How to change browsers language dynamically runtime using Angular

Tags: angular, localization

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'hi' }],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

> How to change browsers language dynamically runtime using Angular. I am using a language dropdowlist by selection of dropdownlist the brosers language should change my english matter in the site to some other language i.e. Hindi without having to keep language specific json in my resource files
> but firstly it is hard coded and secondly it did not work for me